# Data error while building apk in android

Tags: android, redundancy

I am trying to generate unsigned APK it shows error.

Cannot copy 'E:---------------\app\libs\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar' to 'C:\Users--------.AndroidStudio2.2\system\jars\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar'. Reason: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).

i tried adding in code in default config

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and also

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
```

is it necessary toi do disk check ?

any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRC error would indicate data corruption. Try replacing the lib with a fresh copy.

Btw, seeing that it is copying the lib from E: drive to generate the Apk, why don't you try adding the dependency from **Maven Central** from **Project Structure**(assuming you are using Android Studio). Adding it this way will auto manage any issues as it will be stored in with the other libs.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few solutions off the internet I decided to try deleting the .gradle folder and that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem. Just given the same folder for .jks and build output file. Then this problem will be solved.